# Performance problem of updating mongodb with self reference

Tags: mongodb

I am a mongoDB atlas cloud user. I need to update more than 10K documents remotely, all documents in a colleciton, at once.

Currently I tried ".forEach" to self-referencing, but it is too slow and i wonder there is better way.

```
myCollection.find({})
    .forEach(function(o){
      const totalPoint = o.gamepoint + 10
      return myCollection.update(
        {_id: o._id}
      , {
        $set: {
          total = totalPoint 
        }
      }
      );
});
```

there is no problem! but very slow.... Is there no way to improve the perfromance?

If upgrading the hardware is the only way, what should be upgraded between app hosting server and mongodb server?

Update:  My apology. the former code sample is not suit for explaining this problem. this is corrected one.

```
myCollection.find({})
    .forEach(function(o){
      const totalPoint = o.gamepoint + o.gamepoint
      return myCollection.update(
        {_id: o._id}
      , {
        $set: {
          total = totalPoint 
        }
      }
      );
});
```

Comment: I am still searching about this issue. and how is using batchsize() option?

Comment: I set the index and the processing speed is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongo db operator to get desire outcome. [Go here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/).

```
Collection.update({},{$inc: { total: 10}},{multi: true } , function(err, updated){
    console.log('updated')// this will update all documents. 
})
```

Comment: oh..You're right! but  i am sorry. I made a bad example code.  
```javascript
const totalPoint = o.gamepoint + o.gamepoint
```
in this case, I can't use $inc operator.

Answer (score 1):

the following update query will get you there but you will need mongodb server v4.2 for it to work.

```java
db.myCollection.update({}, [{
    $set: {
        total: {
            $add: ["$gamepoint", "$gamepoint"]
        }
    }
}], {
    multi: true
});
```

reference: [Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/update/index.html#update-command-example-agg)

Comment: hi. now i am using 4.0 version, I will select 4.2 version next time. thanks